# Can I read the link-key table?

Tags: java, android, c, bluetooth

I want to save my Bluetooth link-keys table.
(where the data regarding paired devices is stored)

Is there a way to read this data programmatically / physically?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused that you have tags for both Android/Java and 'C', but I'll assume that you are talking about Android.

The Android Bluetooth API is rather limited (even with the NDK) - you can't even come close to a link key.

Come to think of it, I think it would be a security violation if they gave you access to the whole link key table.

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers on this thread mentions a way of getting link keys on android using ADB:
https://superuser.com/questions/229930/finding-bluetooth-link-key-in-windows-7-to-double-pair-a-device-on-dualboot-com

Comment: Thanks. do you know how can i get it programmatically?